# Trigger function once

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

The Preface:
I have a form with a button, after clicking that - jquery function executes. After this closing, and this function still executes one more time.

The problem is - how to execute this function once. Note: it shouldn't be also triggered on refresh action(F5).

Thanks for the help.

P.S Sorry, i can't attach code examples.

P.S.S I tried to make more clear to understand...

Comment: What do you mean by *"After this closing"*

Comment: You need to save state somewhere if you want different behavior before and after refresh. You can use cookies for this, for example.

Comment: Why can you not put code examples in your question? We'll need them if we are to help.

Comment: @br3w5 sorry i can't just because it's companies policy :/

Comment: @Kevin B Closing ops.my fault - by 'this' i meant modal window

Comment: @h3dge It is very strange there to ask somethink abstract. People there don't like abstract questions. Give. Us. Some. Code. :)

Comment: u could just create an example code out of the original source. Can you not? cause without the problem reflecting in the code itself, it is quite difficult to create your scenario. Plus i think, you modal close is reloading the window location, and the jquery that have written is actually on the document ready function which is the cause for it to execute twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need store state somewhere. Here's an overly simple example where we use `hasExecuted` (an arbitrary property I picked) on `localStorage`

```
   if (window.localStorage && !window.localStorage.hasExecuted) {
      window.localStorage.hasExecuted = "true";
      runSomethingThatShouldOnlyRunOnce();
    }
```